# Floating point addition gives wrong result in .NET?

Tags: c#, floating-point-precision

First, to make things clear I am not talking about decimal precision after floating point and I read lots of answers on this. My question is a bit different and I would really like to know why this happens.

So here it is (this was tried in C# .NET 4):

If you have lets say list of 200,000 numbers that are float BUT are actually whole numbers, and lets say these number can be in any range from 1.00F to 500.00F and if you sum them in a loop you get a number X (assuming there is no overflow).

If you have this same list with integers (same numbers) and you sum them in a loop you actually get Y and these numbers are very different with almost up to 5% difference.

We tried this and got results 44 465 501 as X and 43 185 788 as Y result. As you can see this is almost like 110 000 difference. And X is not always bigger than Y (which I would assume should happen if least significant decimal value is not 0).

My thinking was that this only happens if you have actual decimal number (e.g. 3.3 or 124.23) but it seems this also happens if you have whole number but typed as float.

Can anyone tell me why is this? I know that float has an error on least significant decimal value but I didn't know that this also exists when you actually have whole number as float.

Thanks for any answers :)

EDIT, this is how this was tested (in LINQPAD):

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"CONNECTION"))
{
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select total_time = CAST(total_time as int) from test333", connection);
command.Connection.Open();
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
float suma = 0;
while (reader.Read())
suma += (int)reader[0];
suma.Dump();
}
```

The values were:

```
float -> 4,323257E+07
int -> 43125788
```

Sorry the difference was not 1.3mil it was about 110 000

Comment: Show us the code you used to obtain the result.

Comment: I assume by "44.465.501" you mean 44 million, 465 thousand, 501? If so, it would be clearer to use commas than dots.

Comment: @JonSkeet to some cultures, sure. To an international audience, I've seen spaces as separators be the recommended approach: 44 465 501 (to avoid confusion with `,` and `.`, which have opposite meaning in various cultures)

Comment: @TimS. -- It looks like cultures are mixed then:  _1.00F to 500.00F_

Comment: Yep, sure is...maybe because that's how C# code is written? Anyway, some clarification on the OP's part would be good.

Comment: @TimS.: Yes, spaces would be fine and possibly optimal - but commas would definitely be preferred for clarity over dots, I'd say.

Comment: Use a double if you are dealing with integer-valued floating point values that are over 16 million.

Comment: Yes sorry about confusion. It's 44 465 501. And the problem was with 7 digit precision of float it seems...

Comment: @JonSkeet [most European languages except English use comma as decimal point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Hindu.E2.80.93Arabic_numeral_system). The languages that use dot as decimal point are mainly languages that don't use Latin alphabet. The neutral SI style for thousand separator is a space

Comment: @AustinSalonen because most computer programming languages including C# use a dot as decimal point. `1.00F` is just a literal in C#, people don't write it in normal life

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate your problem - I created a test loop to parse a list of numeric "strings" ranging from 1 to 500:

```
void Main()
{
    var r = new Random();

    int count = 200000;
    var nums = Enumerable.Range(1,count)
                            .Select(i => r.Next(500).ToString())
                            .ToList();

    float sumD = nums.Sum(s => float.Parse(s));
    int sumI = nums.Sum(s => int.Parse(s));

    sumD.Dump();
    sumI.Dump();
}
```

`sumD` and `sumI` are within 10 each time (due to the `float` precision limit described below).  either your number lists are different or some numbers contain fractional parts.

This *may* be caused by the precision limit of `float`.  `float` can only store 7 digits of precision, so once the total gets above 7 digits you will lose the least significant digits on the right (e.g. 49,983,710 instead of 49,983,711).

That said - I can't see how the difference would be as dramatic as you illustrate - my first guesses would be:

1. your lists aren't *exactly* equal
2. you list *does* have some fractional parts
3. there's a bug in your summation logic that perhaps exacerbates the precision limit of `float`.

Comment: Actually we tested this with SQL cause we had data in the SQL database. I will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

A `float` has only 24 bits of mantissa, so it can only represent consecutive integers up to 16,777,216. In other words, `16777216f + 1f == 16777216`.

If you use use `double`, you will get 53 bits and will not have this problem until your sum gets to 9,007,199,254,740,992.